# Why Can't I store XML in ASP.NET ListBox Value?

Tags: asp.net, controls

Why does this work:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
string value = lstAvailExtPropsToFilter.SelectedItem.Text +" = "+ txtExtPropToFilter.Text;
string text = lstAvailExtPropsToFilter.SelectedItem.Text + " = " + txtExtPropToFilter.Text;
item.Text = text;
item.Value = value;
lstExtPropsToFilter.Items.Add(item);
```

But not this:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
string value = string.Format("<key>{0}</key><value>{1}</value>", lstAvailExtPropsToFilter.SelectedItem.Text, txtExtPropToFilter.Text);
string text = lstAvailExtPropsToFilter.SelectedItem.Text + " = " + txtExtPropToFilter.Text;
item.Text = text;
item.Value = value;
lstExtPropsToFilter.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to escape the string so it works in HTML.  Try [Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx).

```
Server.HTMLEncode("<key>{0}</key><value>{1}</value>")
```

Then when you need to pull the value you, use [Server.HTMLDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx).

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for the prompt response! BTW, it's "HtmlEncode" not "HTMLEncode".